# Provide request and response body in cucumber report

Tags: java, cucumber, rest-assured, cucumber-java

I use java-cucumber and rest-assured. Currently I try to create report in which I wont to provide full request and response information for each request in report. So the question is:
If it's possible to save in variable all request and response information? Or use another way to get this data in report?

P.S. I know how to get response(`extract().response()`) or print in console logs(`log().all()`) with all request information. And I already setup maven-cucumber-reporting which generating html report, but without all request and response API data.

Comment: You can use the write() method of Scenario and pass in the response-request text. In the Before hook you can pass in the Scenario object and store it inside a instance variable of the step definition class.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This answer shows how you can do it using RestAssured filters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68842731/3059685

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with cucumber but if it has something to capture output for report you may create a filter in REST Assured:

```
import io.restassured.filter.FilterContext;
import io.restassured.filter.OrderedFilter;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.FilterableRequestSpecification;
import io.restassured.specification.FilterableResponseSpecification;

public class RcAllureFilter implements OrderedFilter {

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }

    @Override
    public Response filter(FilterableRequestSpecification requestSpec, FilterableResponseSpecification responseSpec, FilterContext ctx) {
        Response response = ctx.next(requestSpec, responseSpec);
        //you need to implement it, refer to io.restassured.internal.print.RequestPrinter#print
        printRequest(requestSpec.getMethod(), requestSpec.getURI(), requestSpec);
        //you need to implement it, refer to io.restassured.internal.print.ResponsePrinter#print
        printResponse(response, response, response.getStatusLine());
        return response;

    }
}
```

Comment: To avoid having to write your own versions of the internal Request and Response print methods, you can sandwich the `RcAllureFilter` between standard `RequestLoggingFilter` and `ResponseLoggingFilter` filters. The standard filters write the request/response details to a buffer (using the internal methods). That buffer is provided as an argument to the RcAllureFilter constructor. The RcAllureFilter then has the pretty-printed Request/Response contents available to itself in the buffer. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68842731/3059685).

Answer (score 1):

```
import io.restassured.specification.FilterableRequestSpecification;
import io.restassured.specification.FilterableResponseSpecification;
// ...
```

Have tried this and it works fine till I start running tests with `RestAssured` in parallel. This reporting occasionally broken test runs, so I had to comment it out and I'm now also interested in another way how to log request / response data.

Answer (score -1):

If you can consider switching from REST-assured, Karate has the exact capability you are looking for where the detailed HTTP request and response logs appear in-line within the Cucumber HTML report. Here is a [short video demo](https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/899671441221623809).

You can find a detailed comparison of Karate and REST-assured [here](https://github.com/intuit/karate#comparison-with-rest-assured).

Disclaimer: I am the dev.