# Rest Assured with Cucumber: How to put the request information inside the HTML report

Tags: cucumber, rest-assured, cucumber-java

I would like to show my requests and responses details in my HTML report.

A feature file example:

```
Feature: Rest Assured under Cucumber POC

  Scenario: Azure Login Scenario
    Given Request specifications are set with base uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"
    When Azure Login Request Executed
    Then Verify Status Code is 200
```

The Runner class is:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/main/resources/features",
        glue = {""},
        tags = "@tests",
        plugin = {      "pretty",
                        "json:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.json",
                        "html:target/cucumber-reports"}//reporting plugin
)
public class CucumberRunner {}
```

The steps are:

```
@Given("Request specifications are set with base uri {string}")
public void setRequestsSpec(String baseUri){

    RequestSpecification spec = new RequestSpecBuilder()
            .setBaseUri(baseUri)
            .addFilter(new ResponseLoggingFilter())//log request and response for better debugging. You can also only log if a requests fails.
            .addFilter(new RequestLoggingFilter())
            .build();

    testContext().setRequestSpec(spec);
}

@When("^Azure Login Request Executed$")
public void azureLoginExecuted() {

    response =
    given()  //Add x-www-form-urlencoded body params:
        .formParam(GRANT_TYPE_KEY, GRANT_TYPE_VALUE)
        .formParam(AUTO_TEAM_CLIENT_ID_KEY, AUTO_TEAM_CLIENT_ID_VALUE)
        .formParam(AUTO_TEAM_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY, AUTO_TEAM_CLIENT_SECRET_VALUE)
        .formParam(RESOURCE_KEY, RESOURCE_VALUE)
    .when()
        .post(AUTO_TEAM_TENANT_ID + RESOURCE); //Send the request along with the resource

    testContext().setResponse(response);

    setAuthorizationToken();
}

@Then("Verify Status Code is {int}")
public void verifyStatusCode(int expected_repsonse_code) {
    testContext().getResponse().then().statusCode(expected_repsonse_code);
}
```

Currently I found out how to show those details only in my IntelliJ console:

For example:

```
@tests
Feature: Rest Assured under Cucumber POC

  @tests
  Scenario: Azure Login Scenario                                                            # src/main/resources/features/poc.feature:5
    Given Request specifications are set with base uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" # CommonStepsDefinitions.setRequestsSpec(String)
Request method: POST
Request URI:    https://login.microsoftonline.com/6ae4e000-b5d0-4f48-a766-402d46119b76/oauth2/token
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
```

and more..

But the HTML report shows only:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you some details which might not answer your question fully.

In order to add data to Cucumber HTML report you can use:

```
@After
public void addDataToReport(Scenario scenario) { //scenario is provided from Cucumber
    scenario.write(string with the information about scenario);
}
```

It won't be formatted and I don't know how to change how the report displays it. Each of the messages will be under each Test Case.

You have to, somehow, pass the information to `@After` hook.

I hope someone else will answer with more details.

**EDIT:**

In order to store the info about what Scenario is running at the moment, or even in parallel, we can create a class to store necessary information, based on the Thread, so it will be Thread-safe.

Let's create a class to store `Scenario`. Let's call it `Storage`

```
public class Storage {
    private static final HashMap<Thread, Scenario> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static void putScenario(Scenario scenario) {
        map.put(Thread.currentThread(), scenario);
    }

    public static Scenario getScenario() {
        return map.get(Thread.currentThread());
    }
}
```

Now, we have to somehow get the `Scenario`. It can be achieved by using `@Before` hook like this:

```
public class BeforeHook {

    @Before(order = 1)
    public void getScenario(Scenario scenario) {
        Storage.putScenario(scenario);
    }
}
```

`@Before` hooks are run before each scenario. We get the information about Scenario and put it in Storage so we know what Scenario is run on what Thread.
Remember that hooks have to be reachable by the `glue` parameter in Cucumber Runner!

And now, if we want to write additional information to the report:

```
    @Then("Data is saved to the report")
    public void data_is_saved_to_the_report() {
        System.out.println("Saving data to report");
        Storage.getScenario().write("Test data and stuff");
    }
```

We just get current scenario from the Storage and use `Scenario.write()` method to add information to the report.

It will look like this in the report:
[image]

Comment: my ultimate goal is to print request details when it fails. How do I achive that?

Comment: Add if scenario.isFailed or something like that

Comment: Still, given the following scenario:   
Scenario: Multiplication
    Given Multiply test with following data
      | a | b | expected |
      | 1 | 1 |    1     |
      | 2 | 2 |    3     |

I would like to report the wrong values that caused the assertion to fail: 2,2, and 3. I currently can't find it in the Scenario object...

Comment: Read about Data Table in Cucumber

Answer (score 2):

You can log the RestAssured output to your cucumber scenario report by just setting up your `RequestSpecification` filters in this way:

```java
        ByteArrayOutputStream requestResponseBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PrintStream requestResponsePrintStream = new PrintStream(requestResponseBuffer , true);
        List<Filter> loggingFilters = Arrays.asList(
                 new RequestLoggingFilter(requestResponsePrintStream), 
                 new CucumberReportLoggingFilter(requestResponseBuffer, scenario),
                 new ResponseLoggingFilter(requestResponsePrintStream)
        );

        RequestSpecification requestSpecification = RestAssured.given()
                .filters(loggingFilters)
                :
```

where the `CucumberReportLoggingFilter` class looks like this:

```java
class CucumberReportLoggingFilter implements Filter {

    ByteArrayOutputStream requestResponseBuffer;
    Scenario scenario;

    CucumberReportLoggingFilter(ByteArrayOutputStream requestResponseBuffer, Scenario scenario) {
        this.requestResponseBuffer = requestResponseBuffer;
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    @Override
    Response filter(FilterableRequestSpecification requestSpec,
                    FilterableResponseSpecification responseSpec, FilterContext ctx) {
        // Call the next filter(s) which logs the response to the requestResponseBuffer
        Response response = ctx.next(requestSpec, responseSpec);
        scenario.write(requestResponseBuffer.toString());
        return response;
    }
}
```

This solution sandwiches the custom `CucumberReportLoggingFilter` between the standard `RequestLoggingFilter` and `ResponseLoggingFilter` filters.

The sequence of filter events that occur when the RequestSpecification sends a Request is:

1. The standard `RequestLoggingFilter` `filter()` method runs and pretty prints the Request details to the `requestResponseBuffer`.
2. The custom `CucumberReportLoggingFilter` `filter()` method runs and calls the next filter (which is the standard `ResponseLoggingFilter` filter).
3. The standard `ResponseLoggingFilter` `filter()` method runs and pretty prints the Response details to the `requestResponseBuffer`.
4. Control is returned to the custom `CucumberReportLoggingFilter` `filter()` method which sends the contents of the `requestResponseBuffer` to the cucumber report using the `scenario.write()` method.

### Only write out the messages if the scenario fails

You could modify the above solution as follows:

1. Remove the `CucumberReportLoggingFilter`.
2. Make the `requestResponseBuffer` variable 'scenario-scoped' (i.e. only have one buffer per scenario).
3. Have the last `@After` hook that runs in your stepdefs code check the scenario result and if it is failure, write out the contents of the `requestResponseBuffer` to the cucumber report.