# How to write Rest-Assured Request and Response console log to Cucumber report

Tags: java, logging, cucumber, reporting, rest-assured

By default, Rest-Assured writes logs to console.
In case of fail, I need Request and Response attached to the step in the Cucumber report.
I have tried different solutions. But still, in case of fail, I have Request and Response only in console output. 

Rest-Assured logging is activated

```
RestAssured.enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails();
```

My Report looks like this:

[image]

Also, I tried to add Rest-Assured filter configs:

```
RestAssured.filters(new RequestLoggingFilter(), new ResponseLoggingFilter(), new ErrorLoggingFilter());
```

Another my attempt was to add additional ***filter()*** methods to request. Request smth like this:

```
given()
.filter(new RequestLoggingFilter())
.filter(new ResponseLoggingFilter())
.spec(postRequest(param1, param2))
.post(TO_MY_EXAMPLE_ENDPOINT)
.then()
.statusCode(HTTP_OK)
.contentType(JSON)
```

But I receive result as above.

***How to attach Request and Response from Rest-Assured console log to failed step in the report?***


Please help me) I have no idea what to do next(

Comment: @WilfredClement your solution implies a transfer of Response to Hooks.class
In my opinion, it's complicated because a lot of additional coding required.

Comment: @RomanShabanov this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68842731/3059685) shows a way to do it that adds minimal code to your step definitions code.